# SQL можно ли создать поле, ссылающееся на поле из другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, связи

Я новичек в мире БД, допустим есть таблица :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
INT id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, VARCHAR(20) name, INT order_id);
```

И вторая таблица :

```
CREATE TABKE orders (
INT order_id PIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, VARCHAR(20) user_name);
```

Допустим в таблице users есть запись (1, Vlad, NULL).
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при создании в таблице orders записи :

```
INSERT INTO orders VALUES(1, Vlad);
```

в таблице users у пользователя влад поле order_id стало = 1?
Я знаю, что есть первичные ключи, эксперементировал с ними phpmyadmin, но все без толку.. Что я делаю не так? 
*БД - MySQL

Comment: погуглите про триггеры, возможно это то, что вы хотите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы делаете не совсем правильно. В `MySQL` есть первичные ключи и внешние ключи. Внешние ключи есть в типах таблиц `InnoDB`

Структура Ваших таблиц должна быть примерно такой:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  INT id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  VARCHAR(20) name
);

CREATE TABKE orders (
  INT id PIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  INT user_id,
  FOREIGN KEY (iser_id)
    REFERENCES users (id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Vlad');
INSERT INTO orders (id, user_id) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Соответственно вывести всех пользователей с заказами выполнить `select` с использованием `join`

```
SELECT *
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN orders AS ON u.id = o.user_id
```

Comment: т.е связи между таблицами нужны просто для того, что бы если в какой-то из таблиц произошли изменения, то в поле, являющемся внешним ключем для этого поля происходили такие же изменения? (в случае с ON UPDATE CASCADE и ON DELETE CASCADE) мб не совсем правильно сформулировал, но должно быть меня поняли)

Comment: Не совсем так. Внешние ключи больше нужны для сохранение целостности данных. К примеру, если вы удалили по какой-либо причине пользователя, то автоматически удалятся все его заказы. Или изменился ID пользователя, то автоматически изменится его ID в таблице `orders`. Но изменения, к примеру имени пользователя, не повлекут изменения в таблице `orders`. Так же есть нескольколько типов внешних ключей https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html